# Crear URL amigable para que no aparezca el nombre del archivo

Tags: php, .htaccess

Como puedo configurar el archivo htacces para que la url de mi web no sea www.dominio.com/index.php, sino que solo sea www.dominio.com, es una web estatica sin paginas internas.

Comment: Quieres quitarle el index.php a tus sitio? [Por ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/yesidiaz/2064699) Serviría saber que framework estas usando, para ver si se puede solucionar por medio de rutas si es que no quieres quitar el **index.php**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes definir en htaccess que la regla para index.php se sobreescriba para convertirse en la página de inicio por default en tu sitio:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Si no funciona checa si tu proveedor de hosting no tiene un módulo de configuración para htaccess que sobreescriba las reglas que defines en tu archivo.

Saludos.